# mod_rewrite: Check for Custom query string in URL?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use URL rewrite in my new project. But I also need to allow custom query sting in URL.

I just want to know how to write rewrite rule for this URL

> http://www.mysite.com/edit/123/?q1=value1&q2=value2

to become this

> http://www.mysite.com/index.php?action=edit&id=123&q1=value1&q2=value2

The custom query string should be allow unlimited.

Millions of Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do your rule as  any other rule and add the QSA modifier (Query String Append) at the end.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```